# To Load User Details

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a User Records in a Table1. Now I am type one user in Textbox. I show the User Details in my Form.

i.e..,

If I type "User1" (1st record in my table.) in my Textbox. I will be show the User Records in my Form.

```
ID  Name  User Name  UserID Amount
```

These records are shows in orderly other Label Text values.

Note: In this table1 I have used a join query to joining the User Table and Payment Table. The Amount has been calculated.

For example,

```
1 vignesh vkvk 1 6000

2 vignesh vkvk 1 8000

3 krish   kkkk 2 10000

4 vignesh vkvk 1 14000
```

If I type the Username "vkvk" , the sum of the payment sum will be shown in the Payment Label text.

here my code is,

```
  public sub load()

    Rs as new ADODB.Recordset
    Rs.Open("select sum of NetAmount from Table1",con)    
     rs("Payment Amount").value=Lblpaymentsum.Text
  End sub
```

Here I have face a error on the function. But, I can't understand what mistake is done here.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I select one user from this table. the sum of Payment amount will be show my form at the corresponding user which I selected. For example I select a name vkvk in my table record , the payment amount should be shown as 28000

Comment: If i understand you correctly you want to show the _Payment Sum_ for each of the corresponding user you have selected from the table. Is that so??

Comment: yes u are right.

Comment: OK buddy. Edit the question and post some codes for your User records table `Table1` and the control you want to post the output